# Wirelessly Deploy Visual Studio Project Solution to Multiple Hololens 2 Headsets at Once

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, hololens

Title says it all.  Is this possible?  i.e. is there some mechanism in Visual Studio where we can type in multiple IP addresses under `Project -> Properties -> Debugging` so that we can then push `Build -> Deploy Solution` to simultaneously deploy to multiple headsets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one, it is not possible to enter multiple addresses in the user interface in visual studio for deployment.

One could make the .appx package and deploy via MDM solution though like Intune.  This is typically how it is done to distribute to multiple devices in an organization.  Or can use device portal to deploy to each device by IP address.  If you do that though, you might as well just switch out the IP address in visual studio.